# Why aren't tethered balloons used instead of Cellphone towers?

Tags: rf, wireless, telecommunications

If we use tethered balloons with wireless gateways fitted on them (let's say for Cellular or LPWAN communication), they can provide much more coverage. Why aren't they used then?

While there are many instances of high-altitude balloons (like Google's Project Loon, [Space Data SkySite®](https://www.wired.com/2006/01/lofting-balloons-for-cell-service/) or [this question on this StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140801/high-altitude-balloon-communication)), I could find scarce resource on low-altitude tethered balloons.

What I could find was [this work done in 2008 (IEEE Conference Paper)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4798405) by a  research lab. Another recent conference paper (2016) is [this](http://iieng.org/images/proceedings_pdf/E1216004.pdf) from another lab. The first paper also demonstrates that the tethered balloons turn out to be lower cost in the long run.

I wonder how come we don't have tethered-balloon based wireless gateways when they are cheaper and provide more coverage than fixed towers?

Comment: A couple of reports from think tanks saying that Thing 1 is cheaper than Thing 2 does not mean that Thing 1 is a viable business proposition.  So your two reports are not nearly enough factual basis to make the assertions that you do about cost (and, presumably, coverage per $).  Tethered balloons have been a thing for over 100 years, radio has been a thing for over 100 years, there has been ample opportunity for radio antennas to be hoisted by tethered balloons, and there's always *someone* who's enthusiastic about *something*.  I think if it was a viable idea it'd be a thing.

Comment: We can happily ignore the 2008 paper because it couldn't predict the amount of data you'd need to get to and from the airborne base station; also, it completely ignores the fact that IEEE802.11b isn't a feasible standard for wide area coverage **at all**. The 2016 paper is of low analytical quality, and doesn't make any claims regarding financial advantages. Also, it considers WiMAX, not modern cellular standards; WiMAX links are typically modeled to be far more stationary than the average mobile cellular link. I really don't see much backing your claim that this is cheaper.

Comment: Also consider the cost of helium, and that balloons do leak.

Comment: @MarcusMüller : Yes. I am not supporting both these papers; both of them have some flaws. That's why I was mentioning that I could find **scarce** resource.

Comment: Tethered balloons can't hold the RF cables (I'm sure they add a few thousand pounds), the generator, and all of the RF equipment required for a cell tower.  If you did have a tethered balloon cell tower it would probably be the size of a goodyear blimp

Comment: @laptop2d : But for LPWAN networks, the whole RF setup (including batteries and panels) is pretty light-weight (within 20 pounds). Maybe this is not viable for Cellular then, but it is for LPWAN?

Comment: How does your tethered balloon fare in high winds?

Comment: @shivams well, maybe, but that's not what you've been asking in your question, and the general question "what could this technology be useful for" is simply a bottomless pit.

Comment: @shivams Just the risk of the ballon going down alone even though it would be small would be enough for commercial cellular companies from using baloons

Comment: … and a tower basically needs no maintenance at all, while you need to refill the balloon, steer it mechanically in wind, and I honestly wonder how you'd magically do the "large coverage area", "many cells on ground swath" and "light enough antenna to be airborne" combination; there's physics that says this becomes impossible. If you figure that out, tell the satellite communication people. They will literally hand you billions if you can.

Comment: @MarcusMüller : "Large Coverage Area" and "Light Enough Antenna" are not magical. If you look at some LPWAN technologies, e.g. LoRa, their gateways are pretty light. And large coverage area is achieved simply by greater height. While the towers usually max out at 200m, we can take the balloon much higher. E.g. there is a record of [702km](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/article/ground-breaking-world-record-lorawan-packet-received-at-702-km-436-miles-distance) coverage in LoRa using a high-altitude balloon. This is surprising given that LoRa normally has a range of 10 kms.

Comment: @TimWescott : `if it was a viable idea it'd be a thing` Someone would have said the same to many other ideas including Electric Cars. But sometimes, with small technological advances, things drastically change. If in electric cars, it was Lithium (or maybe Elon Musk!), then here it could be LPWAN. Sure there have been radios for 100 years, but LPWAN has just arrived.

Comment: @shivams I'm sorry, but you have no idea what you're talking about. Covering an area with LoRa is something so fundamentally different to what the papers you referred to mentioned, that I'd rather not address it here. I also didn't say "large area" and "light antenna" were mutually exclusive, I said "large area"+"light antenna"+"many ground cells" is hard. Achieving the three together becomes physically impossible because your antenna needs to be high-gain, high-power AND small. Electromagnetic waves don't work like that.

Comment: @shivams and don't diss Tim. You found two extremely low-quality papers which make claims. You discuss them, and Tim raised the very valid point that in a multi-billion industry, it's very unlikely that a known idea of significant financial benefit goes unexplored. He's right – if this was feasible, e.g. project Loon would be in wide deployment. It wasn't feasible, so it's effectively shut down.

Comment: @shivams I think instead of asking "why NOT", you should be understanding why we need elevated points for antennas to begin with (hint: that's changing these days – we still need them, but the trend goes towards smaller cells, and finer-meshed infrastructure. Your balloons do not solve any problems in high-developed countries, but they might make a difference for rural areas, if at all. Your job here would be to understand the theory of electromagnetic waves, antennas, mobile networks, throughput, wireless channels/cellular links.

Comment: I think that instead of asking "why NOT" we should be asking "why is a question about the business viability of non-electrical engineering technologies posted to this stack exchange?"  I apologize for any momentum I may have added to this post by being the first to comment.  I was in error.

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons, I'd say:

A cell phone tower holds many antennas. Need to do maintenance, you go up, fix a given antenna.

Your balloon has many antennas. One needs maintenance. Do you bring the whole balloon down? Find a flying technician?

(And if a balloon cannot hold many antennas, then maybe just build a tower instead?)